# Табулировать функцию

Tags: ассемблер, masm

Не могу сделать log2 в masm64. Как именно применить мне в в моем коде fyl2x? Вот мой код:

```
    include win64a.inc ; библиотеки, см
.data
_x dq 3.0
_op1 dq 3.3
_op2 dq 1.0
_zero dq 0.0
_step dq 0.3
res1 dq 0
res2 dq 0
res3 dq 0
res4 dq 0
res5 dq 0
tit1 db "masm64. Выполнение уравнения на сопроцессоре.",0
buf dq 5 dup(0)
ifmt db "Вывод результата Y = 4,3(x^2 + 1) | Y=3.3*log(2)(x^2+1):",10,10,"Результат:  %d, %d, %d, %d, %d",0ah,0ah,
"Автор: Анатолий",0
.code
WinMain proc
sub rsp,28h; выравнивание стека 28h=40d=32d+8;  8 — возврат
mov rbp,rsp
finit
lea esi,res1
mov ecx, 5
fld1
m1: fld _x
fmul _x
fadd _op2
fmul _op1
fld _x
fadd _step
fstp _x
loop m1
 fisttp res1
 fisttp res2
 fisttp res3
 fisttp res4
 fisttp res5

invoke wsprintf,ADDR buf,ADDR ifmt, res5,res4,res3,res2,res1
invoke MessageBox,0,addr buf,addr tit1,MB_ICONINFORMATION;
invoke ExitProcess,0
WinMain endp
end
```

Comment: Почему ник у тебя "Анна" а автор "Анатолий"?

Comment: _x _po и другие переменные с плавающей запятон должны быть REAL4 или REAL8

Comment: @ИльяК, при регистрации мисскликнул на backspace, вот и половину ника удалилась) спасибо за ответ, но не помогло